# Why is global variable not updated at start, but it's updated at the button press?

Tags: python, kivy

I started working on this small calculator using kivy and I have 2 windows. One with the calculator and one with the result. I have 4 buttons for operations and when I press one of them I want to go to the second window where I have a label which is supposed to be the result. I store the result in a global variable.When I change windows the label gets updated with the default value of the global, but if I press my button I can update with the newest one. Can anyone explain why?

```py
import time
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

ResultVariable = -1

class CalculatorWindow(Screen):
    numberone = ObjectProperty(None)
    numbertwo = ObjectProperty(None)

    def addition(self):
        global ResultVariable
        sm.current="Result"
        ResultVariable=int(self.numberone.text)+int(self.numbertwo.text)
        ResultWindow().updatevalue()
        print(ResultVariable)


    def substraction(self):
        pass
    def multiplication(self):
        pass
    def division(self):
        pass



class ResultWindow(Screen):
    result_number = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ResultWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.updatevalue()

    def updatevalue(self):
        print("It has entered the function")
        self.result_number = str(ResultVariable)

    def restart(self):
        self.result_number = str(ResultVariable)
        #sm.current="Calculator"


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file("graphics.kv")

sm = WindowManager()

screens = [CalculatorWindow(name="Calculator"),ResultWindow(name="Result")]
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)

sm.current = "Calculator"

class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()

print("program ended")
```

And this is the kivy

```
<CalculatorWindow>:
    name: "Calculator"

    numberone: firstone
    numbertwo: secondone

    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: "First number"
            pos_hint: {"x":0.0, "top":0.8}
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1

        Label:
            text: "Second number"
            pos_hint: {"x":0.0, "top":0.6}
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1

        TextInput:
            pos_hint: {"x":0.5, "top":0.8}
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
            id: firstone
            multiline: False

        TextInput:
            pos_hint: {"x":0.5, "top":0.6}
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.1
            id: secondone
            multiline: False

        Button:
            text: "+"
            pos_hint: {"x":0.04, "top":0.35}
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                root.addition()

        Button:
            text: "-"
            pos_hint: {"x":0.28, "top":0.35}
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                root.addition()

        Button:
            text: "*"
            pos_hint: {"x":0.52, "top":0.35}
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                root.addition()

        Button:
            text: "/"
            pos_hint: {"x":0.76, "top":0.35}
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                root.addition()


<ResultWindow>
    name: "Result"

    resultvariable:solution

    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            id: solution
            text: root.result_number
            pos_hint: {"x":0.0, "top":0.8}
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1

        Button:
            text: "Reset"
            pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "top":0.6}
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.4
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
                root.restart()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You have posted more code than I need or want to dig through to find your issue.  Please try to provide a smaller sample of your code that contains your issue.  See the following for a guide on doing so: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
ResultWindow().updatevalue()
```

you create new instance of class `ResultWindow` which has nothing to do with diplayed window which was created in

```
screens = [CalculatorWindow(name="Calculator"), ResultWindow(name="Result")]
```

You have to use

```
screens[1].updatevalue()
```

---

```
import time
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

ResultVariable = -1

class CalculatorWindow(Screen):

    numberone = ObjectProperty(None)
    numbertwo = ObjectProperty(None)

    def addition(self):
        global ResultVariable
        sm.current = "Result"
        ResultVariable = int(self.numberone.text)+int(self.numbertwo.text)
        screens[1].updatevalue()
        print(ResultVariable)

    def substraction(self):
        pass

    def multiplication(self):
        pass

    def division(self):
        pass


class ResultWindow(Screen):

    result_number = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        #super(ResultWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.updatevalue()

    def updatevalue(self):
        print("It has entered the function")
        self.result_number = str(ResultVariable)

    def restart(self):
        self.result_number = str(ResultVariable)
        #sm.current="Calculator"


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file("graphics.kv")

sm = WindowManager()

screens = [CalculatorWindow(name="Calculator"), ResultWindow(name="Result")]
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)

sm.current = "Calculator"

class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

---

**EDIT:** you can also try to use `on_enter()` in `ResultWindow()` which may update every time when kivy shows Screen but you may see how value is changed after scroll screen. I tried to do the same with `on_pre_enter()` but it didn't work for me. See [events for Screen](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.Screen)

```
import time
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

ResultVariable = -1

class CalculatorWindow(Screen):

    numberone = ObjectProperty(None)
    numbertwo = ObjectProperty(None)

    def addition(self):
        global ResultVariable
        sm.current = "Result"
        ResultVariable = int(self.numberone.text)+int(self.numbertwo.text)
        #screens[1].updatevalue()
        print(ResultVariable)

    def substraction(self):
        pass

    def multiplication(self):
        pass

    def division(self):
        pass


class ResultWindow(Screen):

    result_number = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        #super(ResultWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.updatevalue()

    def updatevalue(self):
        print("It has entered the function")
        self.result_number = str(ResultVariable)

    def restart(self):
        self.result_number = str(ResultVariable)
        #sm.current="Calculator"

    def on_enter(self):
        self.updatevalue()

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file("graphics.kv")

sm = WindowManager()

screens = [CalculatorWindow(name="Calculator"), ResultWindow(name="Result")]
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)

sm.current = "Calculator"

class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

Comment: I added examlpe with event `on_enter` but it change little too late so you can see how it changed. `on_pre_enter` didn't work for me but it should update values before manager change screen.